# Are the async/await capabilities in std a replacement for tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

With the addition of async/await into the standard library, is this now a replacement and/or a more recommended approach to using a crate like `tokio`?

Comment: It was not  a replacement, It is  more like global interface for `Future`s. As a result other libraries applied the `Future`s from Rust standards.

Answer (score 4):

They are complementary.

The standard library only contains the bare minimum types and traits, but does not contain a runtime.

Runtimes are intended to be provided by other crates such as `tokio` or `async-std`.